# Overriding a method with the same parameters, but different return types, when inheriting

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, overriding, return-type

I've found several other questions that deal with this topic, but I just can't seem to get it right for my particular situation.  I feel like I've already stumbled across the answer somewhere but just didn't realize it.  I just need a nudge in the right direction to finish this.

I am creating a custom ASP.NET RoleProvider.  Since it inherits from RoleProvider, I have to override public string[] GetAllRoles().  However, I found string[] to be insufficient, so I created a new class called ProjectRole, and made GetAllRoles() return List.

My reason is that my custom Roles table contains more data than just names (IDs, names, descriptions, etc. in multiple languages like DescriptionE, DescriptionJ, etc.), and I'd like to return everything about a role instead of just a name.

So here we are (shortened for brevity's sake)

```
public class ProjectRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override string[] GetAllRoles()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override List<ProjectRole> GetAllRoles()
    {
        List<ProjectRole> rolelist = new List<ProjectRole>();

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sprocGetAllRoles", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows == true)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ProjectRole somerole = new ProjectRole();
                    somerole.ProjectRoleID = reader.GetGuid(reader.GetOrdinal("ProjectRoleID"));
                    somerole.RoleNameE = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("RoleNameE"));
                    somerole.RoleNameJ = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("RoleNameJ"));
                    somerole.DescriptionE = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("DescriptionE"));
                    somerole.DescriptionJ = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("DescriptionJ"));
                    rolelist.Add(somerole);
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        conn.Close();

        return rolelist;
    }

    public class ProjectRole
    {
       private Guid _projectRoleID = Guid.Empty;
       private string _roleNameE = String.Empty;
       private string _roleNameJ = String.Empty;
       private string _descriptionE = String.Empty;
       private string _descriptionJ = String.Empty;

       //public properties to interact with the private fields

       public ProjectRole()
       {
       }
    }
}
```

**The thing that bothers me** is that I can just leave string[] GetAllRoles() alone as unimplemented and name my List GetAllRoles() as something else, like GetRoles(), and then everything is fine.  But then it's really unclear when you are making the call and you see two choices with Intellisense ("which ones do I use?").  Yeah I could use XML comments and say, "Hey, don't use this, use GetRoles instead", but I'd rather just override the return type as well and be done with it.

Comment: If ASP.Net ever calls `GetAllRoles()`, you will fail.  (I don't know whether it does)

Comment: Hah, I was just typing that up as a question as a comment down below on one of the answers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you've presented won't compile, as you're trying to overload just by return type. That's invalid C#. (As is trying to "override" a method signature which isn't specified in the base class.)

But no, in general you can't do this. Indeed, it would be bad if you *could*, because the point of inheritance is that a caller who only knows about the *base* type should be able to write:

```
string[] roles = provider.GetUserRoles();
```

If they can't do that and get back a reasonable result, then you're simply not fulfilling the contract of `RoleProvider`.

You should probably either *not* derive from `RoleProvider` in the first place (if you don't want your class to be used *as* a `RoleProvider`) or you should override `GetAllRoles` in the normal way, and include another method with a different name, which callers who *do* know about your concrete subclass (and who want the extra information) can use.

I would have more sympathy if you were trying to override a method declared to return one type to give a more specific *but still compatible* return type; that's supported by Java, but not C#. For interfaces you can use explicit interface implementation in that case, but the trick doesn't work for abstract classes.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the detailed answer.  Makes sense.  I suppose I don't necessarily *need* to inherit from RoleManager, even though I'm creating my own RoleManager...my worry is the machine will complain somewhere along the line that I'm not using a properly inherited RoleProvider.  If that won't happen anywhere, I guess there's no need to necessarily use the RoleProvider as a base at all.

Comment: Ah, just found an MSDN entry that explicitly says: "When implementing a custom role provider, you are required to inherit the RoleProvider abstract class." (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx) Guess I'll just have to inherit and do it like you suggested...

Comment: @CptSupermrkt: You need to implement a custom role provider *if you're going to use other infrastructure which uses `RoleProvider`* - but if you're doing your own role-based system from the ground up then you don't *have* to use any of the built-in role mechanisms.

Answer (score 2):

It is fundamentally impossible to change the return type of an override.

What would happen if you write

```
string[] roles = ((RoleProvider)new ProjectRoleProvider()).GetAllRoles();
```

Instead, you should mark the override as `[Obsolete]` (note that that will generate a compiler warning).

However, I would recommend renaming your version to `GetRolesDetail()` to more clearly demonstrate the difference.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know about the [Obsolete] property :)

Is there anything else I should know about doing this in regards to a custom RoleProvider?  Like is some kind of machine code or process ever going to try and call that GetAllRoles() method I marked as obsolete?